# How to pull all data in the table using aws cli?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, command-line-interface

I have a table on dynamodb with about 50,000 records. I want to pull this whole table to my local computer using aws cli. But I know there is a 1MB limit.
What I've done so far

- Get data in json format using `aws dynamodb scan --table-name my_table_name> output.json`

Then, Convert json output to dataframe using the python code below.

```
import json
import pandas as pd
with open("output.json", encoding='utf-8-sig', errors='ignore') as json_data:
   data = json.load(json_data, strict=False)
 
df=pd.DataFrame(data["Items"])
```

- After, necessary preprocessing steps...

Is there a way I can pull the whole table?

Comment: So `data["LastEvaluatedKey"]` should be a key that you can pass to `aws dynamodb scan  --table-name my_table_name --starting-token <LastEvaluatedKey> output.json`.  That being said, it will be really annoying to bounce back and forth between the CLI and Python and you'd probably be better off doing it all in Python with `boto3`.

Comment: I think working with aws cli is more secure. am i thinking wrong ?

Comment: I don' think there is anything really "more secure" with the CLI compared to Python, but it's really a matter of preference. If you like shell scripting, you can indeed do this in the shell - you can even use "jq" instead of Python to process the JSON object. But I would personally just do the whole thing in Python, if you're comfortable with that language.